# Update month of all records in datetime column mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to change month of all dates in datetime field of mysql.

I can do this in PHP but I am looking for a query to update month of all dates to September for example.

Comment: Seems trivial https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add but don't forget september has 30 days and february 28

Comment: @P.Salmon we can have only change dates of columns that are valid for the said month by adding a WHERE condition, i.e `WHERE DAY(created_at) <= 30` for september.